# Open GridView2 by selecting GridView1 field

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to make every time I select a specific field within **GridView1**, it opens related data in an Access Database in **GridView2**.

This is the code on my page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" CodeBehind="MainView.aspx.vb" Inherits="DosimetryASPNET_WebApplication.MainView" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnMenuView" runat="server" Text="Return to Menu" Width="200px" OnClick="btnMenuView_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder4" runat="server">
    <br />
    <br />

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BatchID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchID" HeaderText="BatchID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="BatchID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Product" HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="Product" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchSize" HeaderText="BatchSize" SortExpression="BatchSize" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Priority" HeaderText="Priority" SortExpression="Priority" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StartReq" HeaderText="StartReq" SortExpression="StartReq" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString1 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [AllBatches]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BatchID" Visible="False">
    </asp:GridView>

</asp:Content>
```

This is the code I use to populate **GridView1**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim dt As New Northwind.AllBatchesDataTable
        Using da As New NorthwindTableAdapters.AllBatchesTableAdapter
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using
            GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
            GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I am using an Access database and for populate **GridView2** I use a second table.

For **GridView1** I use the "**AllBatches**" table with the following columns:
**BatchID** - **Product** - **BatchSize** - **Priority** - **StartReq** - **Status**

For **GridView2** I want the table "**IngredientsTable**" to be called. It contains the following columns:
**LotManufactID** - **Ingredient** - **Actual** - **Target** - **Minimum** - **Maximum** - **WeighinhDate** - **Status** - **IDBatchID**

In my Access database, the table works like I'd like it to work in ASP.NET.
When I click on the "**BatchID**" of the "**AllBatches**" it opens a secondary table in the row below the line that I clicked with the "**IngredientsTable**" data.
I created a relationship in the bank between the two tables.

It may be too complex to do this, but I need help developing this functionality that at least opens in **GridView2** the "**IngredientsTable**" data that relates to the "**BatchID**" of the "**AllBatches**".

I hope you have succeeded in exemplifying my doubt and being clear.
I'm waiting for help.

Answer (score 0):

One of many possible solutions:
- declare a "select" field in GridView1
- define GridView2 columns
- when select field is clickes, onSelectedIndexChanged is raised, and in that event you read the BatchID of the clicked row, perform a query on the ingredients table and display results on GridView2

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BatchID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchID" HeaderText="BatchID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="BatchID"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product" HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="Product" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchSize" HeaderText="BatchSize" SortExpression="BatchSize" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Priority" HeaderText="Priority" SortExpression="Priority" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StartReq" HeaderText="StartReq" SortExpression="StartReq" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BatchID" Visible="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LotManufactID " HeaderText="LotManufactID" SortExpression="LotManufactID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Ingredient " HeaderText="Ingredient" SortExpression="Ingredient" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Actual " HeaderText="Actual" SortExpression="Actual" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Target " HeaderText="Target" SortExpression="Target" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Minimum " HeaderText="Minimum" SortExpression="Minimum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Maximum " HeaderText="Maximum" SortExpression="Maximum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="WeighinhDate  " HeaderText="WeighinhDate" SortExpression="WeighinhDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status  " HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IDBatchID " HeaderText="IDBatchID" SortExpression="IDBatchID" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and the code

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int BatchID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[GridView1.SelectedIndex].Value;
    //Access Ingredients with batchID
    var dtIngredients = new DataTable(); // create datasource with a query
    GridView2.Visible = true;
    GridView2.DataSource = dtIngredients;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```